# Does YOLOv7 pose estimation model output 3D points? ... And, how to get them?

Tags: yolo

Simple question. Does [YOLOv7 pose estimation model](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7#pose-estimation) output 3D points? ... And, how to get them?

NOTE: I have already run the `test.py` over custom images (successfully) with the object detection model.

Answer (score 1):

I am also seeking 3D pose estimation tool too.

Sadly, output of YOLOv7 is 2D, the x, y and the confidence score, so there is a 3*17=51 length tensor.

There is a guy tried to use 2 cameras and YOLO to do the 3D estimation, you may take a look.
https://github.com/SkalskiP/sport

Comment: I guess, then, that the only AI (apart OpenPose, maybe?) that outputs 3D poses is https://smpl-x.is.tue.mpg.de/ (regrettably I am not able to make it work).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, YOLOv7 is for 2D pose estimation for multi-person pose-estimation, where models like MediaPipe does single-person pose-estimation.

For the 3D pose estimation, I am using the "3D-MPPE" model, since the pretrained models are provided. It is a single person 3D Pose Estimation model.

The 3D-MPPE model has 2 inner models: RootNet and PoseNet.

The RootNet estimates the root depth, which is the z-axis value of the target (relative distance from camera to the target).
And the 3D-MPPE PoseNet estimates both x and y axis values of each target joints of the person.

Below are links for 3D-MPPE official repos (for both PoseNet and RootNet), and article for actual usage of the 3D-MPPE model:

[3D MPPE PoseNet github repo](https://github.com/mks0601/3DMPPE_POSENET_RELEASE)

[3D MPPE RootNet github repo](https://github.com/mks0601/3DMPPE_ROOTNET_RELEASE)

[Estimating 3D pose for athlete tracking using 2D videos and Amazon SageMaker Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/machine-learning/estimating-3d-pose-for-athlete-tracking-using-2d-videos-and-amazon-sagemaker-studio/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's 3D since when I investigated the numeric output for each pedestrian I receive 3*17 = 51 length tensor.

Comment: Thanks but... How to get them? Any clue?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).